# How to work with Basic and Forms authentication simultaneosly in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net side that right now works with Forms Authentication. I'm implementing several Rest webservices with Web API and, in order to use them outside the browser context (e.g. a console app) it feels like I'll need Basic Authentication (refer to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/forms-authentication)

However, when I try to enable both Forms and Basic Authentication at the same time in IIS, IIS Manager tells me the following: "Challenge-based and login redirect-based authentication cannot be used simultaneously".

What should I do and how can I enable Basic Authentication so I can use Web API services outside a browser context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post which solves your issue http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html

Comment: That looks good, tomorrow I'll check it out and come back with feedback! Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the approach described in the article and, although I had to do several modifications to make it work, it's still giving me some headaches in the services. I'll keep investigating the issue though, as your approach provided a great step forward to solve my issue.